# What are the First Partial Derivatives of $x^y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

The problem I have are from the first partial derivatives of $f(x,y) = x^y$
What is its $f_x(x,y)$ and $f_y(x,y)$?

I need to find the critical points of $f(x,y) = x^y  + 4xy - 2y^2  + 5$, but the $x^y$ is making me confused.
The answer I get when I try to find its partial derivatives are
$f_x(x,y) = yx^{y-1}+4y$
$f_y(x,y) = x^y\ln x+4x-4y$
I am stuck in this step and I am not sure if my partial derivatives are right.

Comment: Do you want to verify an answer that you have? Also, have you seen the formula for the derivatives of the functions $f(x) = x^n$ and $f(x) = a^x$, where $n,a$ are fixed?

Comment: What have you done? Where are the difficulties you're facing ?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Use the definition of $x^y$, which is $\mathrm e^{y\ln x}$.

Comment: @Bernard That's not necessarily the definition. There are a few other common options. But I agree that that might be the easiest way to reach a solution.

Comment: I added some details to the question.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard, I will try to implement that definition in my solution. Hopefully it works.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes, I indeed want to verify my doubtful answers. I know the derivative of $a^x$ but I'm not sure about $x^n$. Should it be $nx^{n-1}$?

Comment: Yes, $\frac d{dx} x^n = nx^{n-1}$. But also note that in general $4x-4y \neq 0.$

Comment: Thanks @DavidK, I've made such a basic mistake. Now correcting it.

Comment: I think you have the answer to your question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if our function is:

$$ f(x,y) = x^y$$

Then,

$$ \frac{ \partial f}{\partial x} = y x^{y-1}$$

And,

$$ \frac{ \partial f}{ \partial y} = \frac{ \partial x^y}{\partial y}= \frac{ \partial}{\partial y} e^{ y \ln x} = e^{ y \ln x} \frac{\partial (y \ln x)}{\partial y} $$

Comment: Thank you again @mattos I should have been more careful

Comment: Ah, so that's why I've been going in circles since earlier and can't seem to equate $x^y$ and $e^{x ln y}$ no matter what method I use. Haha. Thank you also @mattos and Buraian.

Comment: @cerebrus6 We have $x^y = e^{\ln(x^y)}$, by the definition of logarithm, and $e^{\ln(x^y)} = e^{x\ln y}$ by standard logarithm properties. Or it could be that $x^y = e^{y\ln x}$ is how you _define_ $x^y$ for real positive $x$ and real $y$.